# What is my model learning- Linear vs Non-Linear

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to validate if my understanding of the topic is right.

> Linear Models pick up on a single representation of a class (read can only pick one) whilst a Non-Linear Model like a Neural Network is able to learn **multiple representations** of each class.

If that is the case then doesn't that make linear models less effective then their counterparts, albeit model computation times will be much slower.

PS: I have been referring to the material from Stanford [cs231n](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3) to arrive at this conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

For classification problems, you can view linear model as a "hyperplane", and this is also why we call it "linear", because it is a line in high dimensional space. Here is the 1D,2D,3D example.

Details can be found in my other answer here

[What could be an intutive understanding of a hyperplane?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475669/what-could-be-an-intutive-understanding-of-a-hyperplane/475672#475672)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nonlinear models can have more flexibility, but this need not be desirable. With that flexibility comes increased ability to overfit to your training data, detecting mere coincidences that will not be present in new data. The major goal of predictive modeling and machine learning is to make predictions on data where you don’t know the answer.

What is a stock price going to be tomorrow?

How many new COVID cases will there be by the end of July?

What word did this person say to Alexa?

It is easier to trick complex models than simple models.

Comment: Yes, I now understand that in a more predictive setup linear models are effective. Addressing your overfit hypothesis, something that has always confused me is, in non-linear models is this noise learned merely my statistical significance?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Perhaps you can post as a separate question and include more detail.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. Most times models predict un-seen data with the statistically significant class label. I was trying to piece two and two, so never-mind. Thank you, Dave.

Comment: What do you mean by a statistically significant class label?

Comment: Let's say I have four classes l1,l2, l3, l4 that the model is trained on. Now, l1 has 100k data points in train while the other three have significantly fewer data. In such cases, in the linear context, I have seen data points containing unseen data get predicted as l1, ie statistically significant class.

Comment: Well if most of the observations are label 1, I would hope that most of them would be labeled as such! Why do you see that as a problem? Perhaps this warrants a separate question.